# Trouble compiling GLFW, undefined symbols

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, cmake, clion

I'm currently reading [this tutorial on OpenGL](https://open.gl/context#GLFW). I'm getting compile errors as follows:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_glfwInit", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwTerminate", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [OpenGL] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/OpenGL.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/OpenGL.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [OpenGL] Error 2
```

Now I'll list my current setup, starting with my main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <thread>

int main() {
    glfwInit();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Here's my Cmake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(OpenGL)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(OpenGL ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

And finally my command line arguments:

```
-lglfw -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -
framework IOKit -framework CoreVideo
```

I'm using CLion, and I believe I've compiled it correctly. I'm just trying to get a blank window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you specifying libraries on the command line if you're using CMake? Put a `target_link_libraries` directive into your `CMakeLists.txt` for that.