# Minimal example with GLFW fails because of undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, cmake, clion

I am trying to compile the following minimal example for `GLFW`:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <thread>

int main() {
    glfwInit();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

My `CMakeLists.txt` file is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(viewer)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package(glfw3 3.2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(viewer main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(viewer ${GLFW_LIBRARIES})
```

If I try to compile the code, it fails with the following error message:

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable visualiser
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_glfwInit", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwTerminate", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [visualiser] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/visualiser.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/visualiser.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [visualiser] Error 2
```

I see the similar questions, e.g.:

- [Trouble compiling GLFW, undefined symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43817344/trouble-compiling-glfw-undefined-symbols)
- http://dudandan.com/2017/02/15/Setup-glfw-and-glew/

But their solutions did not really help.

**UPD:** Following the comment of @thomas_f, I modified my `CMakeLists.txt` file as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(viewer)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package(glfw3 3.2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GLFW3_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(viewer main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(viewer ${GLFW3_LIBRARY})
message(GLFW LIB: ${GLFW3_LIBRARY})
```

I also made sure that there is no `CMakeCache.txt` in my build directory:

```
$ ls -a
.                 ..                .idea             CMakeLists.txt    cmake-build-debug main.cpp
```

However, I still get the same error message. It seems, that

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" ........./viewer
GLFWLIB:
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/denis/Documents/projects/theia/code/visualiser/cmake-build-debug

[Finished]
```

So it seems that `${GLFW3_LIBRARY}` is not defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `glfw3Config.cmake`:

```
# - Config file for the glfw3 package
# It defines the following variables
#   GLFW3_INCLUDE_DIR, the path where GLFW headers are located
#   GLFW3_LIBRARY_DIR, folder in which the GLFW library is located
#   GLFW3_LIBRARY, library to link against to use GLFW
```

It seems that you are referencing the wrong variables. Also, there is no need to invoke `include_directories()` in this case, since GLFW is obviously installed in a standard location, i.e. your compiler already knows where to find it.

**Edit**: I was able to reproduce the linker error and changing the variable name to `GLFW3_LIBRARY` fixed it.

**Clarification**: Change your link command to: `target_link_libraries(viewer ${GLFW3_LIBRARY})`

**Update if you're on Mac OS**: If you're experiencing the same issues as OP, it may be because `glfw3Config.cmake` does **not** export the variables mentioned in my answer. Instead it creates an imported library, `glfw`. In this case, the correct way to link to `glfw` would be to simply do this: `target_link_libraries(<target> glfw)`.

If `glfw` was installed using `brew`, you should find the `.cmake`-files under: `/usr/local/Cellar/glfw/<version>/lib/cmake/glfw3`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried to use `include_directories(${GLFW3_INCLUDE_DIR})` and `target_link_libraries(viewer GLFW3_LIBRARY)`, but didn't actually work. However it seems it works with `target_link_libraries(viewer glfw)`.  Do you have any idea why? You could update your reply and I accept it.

Comment: @desa Updated. I think you just forgot to deference the variable? `target_link_libraries(viewer ${GLFW3_LIBRARY})` as opposed to `target_link_libraries(viewer GLFW3_LIBRARY)`.

Comment: @desa As for your other question, why `target_link_libraries(viewer glfw)` works: This is the same as adding `-lglfw` to your linker flags. Since `glfw` is installed in a standard location in this case, the linker knows where to look for it. More here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/target_link_libraries.html

Comment: Thank you for clarification. But I still do not get why target_link_libraries(viewer ${GLFW3_LIBRARY}) still does not work then

Comment: First, try removing `CMakeCache.txt` (located in your build directory), then build again. Second, could you tell me the output of the command `message("GLFW LIB: ${GLFW3_LIBRARY}")`?

Comment: I updated the question with the info. Could you tell me where should I check `glfw3Config.cmake`?

Comment: @desa I updated my answer, it seems that these variables may not be set at all when using MacOS. I was testing this under Linux, but I just verified using a Mac. My apologies for making the assumption that it would be the same on all Unix-based platforms.

Comment: thank you a lot for making it clear! Your answer is really helpful!